# Apostrophe in Data Extension comes back as gobbledygook

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, json, dataextensions

I have a page making an ajax call to the function below. The Description field has apostrophe's in it. They look fine in the data extension, but when ampscript grabs them from the DE, they look like junk for example, youâ€™re instead of you're. Is there any way around this? The way I am getting my data into the DE is by saving an XLS file as CSV with utf-8 encoding, then opening in notepad and saving again as utf-8. This gives me a nice clean file to import and when imported there do not appear to be any weird characters in the data extension. Not from the Marketing Cloud side anyway. I even tried just saving the CSV file straight away, without utf-8 encoding, but it still doesn't work. Instead it returns different garbled characters. I know it's the ampscript and not the json array causing the issue because I did a simple test with a landing page and just ampscript and I still get the characters.

```
 Set @id = Trim(requestParameter("id"))
  Set @course = LookupRows(@DE_courses, "ID", @id)
  If RowCount(@course) == 0 Then
      Set @status = "0 courses with that ID."
      Output(v(@status))
  ELSE
    Set @rowCount = RowCount(@course)


      SET @currentRow = Row(@course, 1)
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, "{")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """Id""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "Id"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """Status""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "Status"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """RestrictedCode""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "RestrictedCode"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """CourseName""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "CourseName"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """Description""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "Description"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """Audience""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "Audience"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """AttendanceMax""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "AttendanceMax"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """AttendanceMin""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "AttendanceMin"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """RoomReserved""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "RoomReserved"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """Room""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "Room"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """Duration""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "Duration"), """,") 
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """Cost""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "Cost"), """,") 
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """LocationCity""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "LocationCity"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """LocationRegion""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "LocationRegion"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """LocationCountry""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "LocationCountry"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """Notes""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "Notes"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """Prework""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "Prework"), """,")
      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, """CancellationPolicy""",": ", """", Field(@currentRow, "CancellationPolicy"), """")

      Set @coursesObject = Concat(@coursesObject, "}")

      Set @result = Concat("[", @coursesObject, "]")


        Output(v(@result))
      ENDIF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, the page encoding in the microsite needs to be set to UTF-8